# Better way to execute iterative function for very large dataset in python

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, iteration

```
for i in range(1,len(df_raw)):
    if df_raw.loc[i-1, 'A']!= 0 & df_raw.loc[i, 'A']== 0 & df_raw.loc[i+1, 'A']== 0:
        df_raw.loc[i,'B'] = df_raw.loc[i+5,'B']
```

hi all,
i m trying to run this above line of code on my data.
till the time data is of range 100,000-150,000 rows , i am able to run this code but for bigger size of data it just keeps on running with no output.
Can u pls hlp me with better way of writin this code for bigger data sizes.

Comment: Please explain the logic you are trying to do here (your code) so it'll be easier for people to solve what you want in a more efficient way.
Also, providing a sample dataframe (even with 5 rows) will help understand your columns and your logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that your code is just taking a long time to run because of the large number of steps it has to take. (more than 150,000). There are a few things I would recommend doing:

1. See if you need to be running the code for every one of the elements in your array. If not, this will *dramatically* improve performance.
2. Check `top`/task manager/system monitor (depending on operating system) and see if you've run out of ram.
3. Change out your bitwise and (`&`) for the more-idiomatic and faster (shortcircuiting) `and`
4. [Profile your code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582336/how-can-you-profile-a-python-script)
5. Add a progress bar:
   At the command line: `pip install tqdm`
   In your code

```py
from tqdm import tqdm

for i in tqdm(range(1,len(df_raw))):
    if df_raw.loc[i-1, 'A'] != 0 and df_raw.loc[i, 'A'] == 0 and df_raw.loc[i+1, 'A']== 0:
        df_raw.loc[i,'B'] = df_raw.loc[i+5,'B']
```

5. Consider `multiprocessing`. If you can split the code up into descrete segments, you can parallelize it on a multi-core system. This can be difficult to do correctly, so I would start with the above steps. If you decide to go with this route and need help, edit your question with a more complete code sample.

Comment: thanx a lot for the reply... just a small change from '&' --> 'and' , has improved the speed a lot.... Aslo tqdm helps well in visualising the progress....

Answer (score 1):

I think the method you're missing which efficiently performs this kind of logic is [shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html?highlight=shift#pandas.Series.shift). Here's my proposal:

```
df_raw = df_raw.sort_index() # Optional, if index is not sorted
df_raw['A_is_zero'] = df_raw['A'] == 0
df_raw['prev_A_is_zero'] = df_raw['A_is_zero'].shift(1).fillna(True)
df_raw['next_A_is_zero'] = df_raw['A_is_zero'].shift(-1).fillna(False)
B_to_change = df_raw['A_is_zero'] & df_raw['next_A_is_zero'] & ~df_raw['prev_A_is_zero']
df_raw.loc[B_to_change, 'B'] = df_raw['B'].shift(-5).loc[B_to_change]
```

Since you didn't provide a sample dataframe I didn't test it though, so I can't guarantee it'll work, but I think I provided the main idea to reach the solution. For instance in the four rows before the last, if `B_to_change` is True, you'll get NaNs in 'B'. One other thing is that you're using `.loc` with integers, but I didn't know if your index is a range, in which case my first line is useless, or if it's not and you meant to use `iloc` (see [this link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing) about the `loc` / `iloc` difference), in which case my first line should be removed because it would not lead to the expected result.

---

EDIT:

> my requirements has some iterative conditional sequential operations,
> e.g.:
>
> ```
> for i in range(1, len(df_raw)):
>     if df_raw.loc[i, 'B'] != 0:
>         df_raw.loc[i, 'A'] = df_raw.loc[i-1, 'A']
> ```

In this case (which you should have specified in your question), you can use forward filling as follows:

```
B_is_zero = df_raw['B'] == 0
df_raw['new_A'] = None
df_raw.loc[B_is_zero, 'new_A'] = df_raw.loc[B_is_zero, 'A'] 
df_raw['A'] = df_raw['new_A'].fillna(method='ffill')
```

Once again, you should be careful of how you handle the edge case where 'B' is nonzero on the first row.

Comment: thanx for the reply... but my requirements has some iterative conditional sequential operations which are not possible using "shift" method. 

for eg:

           ` for i in range(1,len(df_raw)):`
                `if df_raw.loc[i, 'B'] != 0:` 
                     `df_raw.loc[i,'A'] = df_raw.loc[i-1,'A'] `

Comment: @tausifshams note that this can still be vectorized. TLouf's updated `ffill` code is probably simplest, and it will be much faster than looping.